# How to properly work with literal types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to learn TS for the first time, but there is one case, which does not click quite well in my mind. Let's say we have two variables:

```
let value1: 'POST' | number | boolean = 'POST';
let value2: 'POST' | number | boolean | string = 'POST';
```

And let's say we have another variable to which we want to assign one of the variables specified above:

```
let copiedValue: 'POST'
```

When I assign to the variable **copiedValue** variable labeled **value1** it works okay, but when I attempt to assign **value2** complier shows me an error and I have to cast it to get rid of this error. I suppose that is because of additional *string* type that I added to **value2** variable and TS compiler just warns that if something is labeled as a *string* it can be anything and not only 'POST', but is not it a problem that **value1** variable has *boolean* and *numeric* types set on it too? Also, if TS compiler allows **value1** because it knows that this variable holds "POST" at the moment of assignment to **copiedValue** variable, what is a problem with **value2** variable if it also holds absolutely the same "POST" value?

Comment: post is of string type

Answer (score 1):

If `copiedValue` is of type `'POST'`, that's the only value it can accept. You shouldn't be able to assign `value1` or `value2` to it as far as type is concerned.

Typescript may be smart enough to see that in this particular case, `value1` is explicitly assigned the value `'POST'` and so it can safely assign it to `copiedValue` regardless, but that would just be a convenience it's giving you since the value is known at compile time.

Yes I think you're right that it's not able to do that in the case of `value2` because there's ambiguity there as to whether `'POST'` should be considered type `'POST'` or type `string`.

Generally, typing anything `'EXPLICIT STRING HERE' | string` is going to give you these kinds of problems. I would say in (nearly?) every case, you want to enumerate all possible string values *or* type something as `string`, but not both.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. "...value2 because there's ambiguity there as to whether 'POST' should be considered type 'POST' or type string..." - that part was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> is not it a problem that value1 variable has boolean and numeric types set on it too?

In general, yes it is.

However, in your case you have assigned `'POST'` to `value1`. This allows the compiler to infer that, at that point in the program, until something else is done with `value1`, it is of type `'POST'`. With the type so inferred, assignment to `copiedValue` *is* permissible.

Try initialising `value1` with value `false` and you will see that you get an error.

> Also, if TS compiler allows value1 because it knows that this variable holds "POST" at the moment of assignment to copiedValue variable, what is a problem with value2 variable if it also holds absolutely the same "POST" value?

In the case of `value2`, the added type `string` means that, under the rules of the compiler, it cannot be determined whether `value2` is of type `'POST'` or `string` at the relevant point in the code. The compiler would not appear to be sophisticated enough to do that.

For the compiler to do that it would require it checking that no manipulation of the string contents of the value of `value2` had not been done (eg to add a character to turn its value from `'POST'` into `'POSTS'`). It's easy to imagine that adding such a feature is not a priority of the TypeScript team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really helpful. May I ask you another question as well to further clarify my doubts? Does TS look at the actual value of a variable when this variable is assigned to another one? So, if "value2" holds "POST" value and then we immediately assign it on the next line to "copiedValue" variable, then there is no space to somehow modify "POST" value, but that still does not seem to work. The only case is that TS compiler looks only at the type of "value2" variable and because value "POST" can be either "POST" or "string" it chooses broader type. Am I right?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking... we couldn't assign value2 to copiedValue (because it could be of type string) and we can't legitimately ask questions of a program beyond an error. If you assign value1 to copiedValue it works as you expect. In general, I wouldn't think of TS as "looking at the value". It gives a type to each variable at any given point in the program execution using its ruleset (one of which might be looking at what values are assigned). All inference at later points in the program is done on those types.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't say that TS chooses the "broader type" between 'POST' and string. The compiler is trying to narrow down the type union. If it doesn't have enough information, it will not narrow down the type union and keep it as a union of some kind. The fact that it does narrow down the union when you assign 'POST' to value1 is actually an added feature of the compiler. It would be easy to imagine that the compiler wouldn't narrow down the type union of value1 on the assignment.

Comment: Thanks once again for such detailed explanations.